# yii2: Backend login makes website go down. Temporarly

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user, yii2-validation

At first 1 month when the website was uploaded, both backend and frontend worked fine. Then without any coding changes to the application, frontend is working fine, whenever I tried to login to backend, error pops like "the page isn't redirecting properly". After login attempt to backend even frontend won't be accessible, until the IP provided by ISP is changed.(i.e router being restarted.)

Comment: Hard to say. It could `.htaccess` file or something with your ISP specifically.

Comment: Please check your server log. It will helpful to identify the issue.